# Django Admin modifications for existing extensions (django_taggit)

Tags: python, django, admin, django-taggit

In a Django project i installed the django_taggit extension. It integrates well with the Django admin interface. I have two problems though:

### Problem A: `flatchoices`

I cannot show a comma-seperated tag list in the list view of my taggable model. Meaning:

```
# models.py
class Topic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)

# admin.py
class TopicAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'tags')

admin.site.register(Topic, TopicAdmin)
```

Throws an error:

```
AttributeError: 'TaggableManager' object has no attribute 'flatchoices'
```

Question: **How can i add the functionality i need without changing the extension sources so that i am still able to do updates?**

### Problem B: `prepopulated_fields`

If i navigate to the "Add Tag" admin view i can add new tags (naturally). There are two mandatory fields: **name** and **slug**.

I want the slug to be prepoluated via `prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("name",)}`, so that i do not have to type in the slug manually.

Question: **How can i add the `prepopulated_fields` property?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use [official docs](http://django-taggit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/admin.html) wisely
2. Make your own admin class for tags (inherit it of taggit's admin), then use:

   ```
   admin.site.unregister(Tag)
   admin.site.register(Tag, YourTagClass)
   ```

Comment: looks like i don't need taggit at all, and should code my own tagging app from the scratch

Comment: It depends. If you need only small piece of the functionality - maybe, yes. But if you need also tag clouds, and all stuff, and all other stuff (or probably will need it need in the future) then you'd better improve 3rd party library.